# How to trigger a local notification when phone goes to lock screen ios

Tags: ios, notifications, audio-recording, lockscreen

I have an audio recording app, and I'm trying to notify the iPhone user that the app is recording when the app is recording from the lock screen.

I tried to use `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, but from my research you can't get rid of the rewind and fastforward buttons that pop up on the lock screen. Those buttons are irrelevant to recording, so I would rather not have them.

So now I'm trying to find out, how can I send a notification that the app is recording when the lock screen becomes active?

Answer (score 0):

MayBe you can do this in AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if (....)
    {
        UILocalNotification *notification=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        ......
    }

}
```